# Making views appear at unique random positions in android screen

Tags: android, android-view, android-screen, android-screen-pinning

I am trying to develop a brain turning game in android a bit like einstien challenge game. I want the multiple circular image views of same size appear at unique random positions each time user goes to new level. Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely need to generate random positions using

```
Random r = new Random();
int position1 = r.nextInt(30 - 10) + 10;
```

This will generate random number between 10 inclusive and 30 exclusive.